# np.random.dirichlet with small parameter: embed future solution in current numpy

Tags: python, numpy, random, dirichlet

There is an ongoing discussion about the current `np.random.dirichlet` function, as it does not function for small parameters:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(3)*.00001)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-464b0fe9c6c4> in <module>()
----> 1 np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(3)*.00001)

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.dirichlet (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:25213)()

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.dirichlet (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:25123)()

ZeroDivisionError: float division
```

The discussion can be read [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/5872) and [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5851) and points out, that it is a normalization error. Currently the proposed enhancement to switch samplers for small parameters cannot be merged into master of numpy for several reasons.

**Question**: Can someone suggest a different way to draw dirichlets in python or point me to a solution to use the new sampler without recompile my numpy and/or working on an unreleased branch?

Comment: Did you try sampling using beta variate? It is described in Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Random_number_generation

Comment: As pointed out in the provided links, the `numpy.dirichlet` uses the `numpy.beta` distribution to sample. For small parameter the beta returns `[Nan, Nan]` instead of altering between `[1,0]` and `[0,1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, lets try the following. Here is Beta(alpha,beta) variate sampling which should work for any small numbers.

```
import math
import random

def sample_beta(alpha, beta):
    x = math.log( random.random() )
    y = math.log( random.random() )

    return x / (x + y*alpha/beta)

# some testing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bins = [0.01 * i for i in range(102)]
plt.hist([sample_beta(0.00001, 0.1) for k in range(10000000)], bins)
plt.show()
```

Using it, you might try to sample Dirichlet via Beta variate as described in the wikipedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Random_number_generation

```
params = [a1, a2, ..., ak]
xs = [sample_beta(params[0], sum(params[1:]))]
for j in range(1,len(params)-1):
    phi = sample_beta(params[j], sum(params[j+1:]))
    xs.append((1-sum(xs)) * phi)
xs.append(1-sum(xs))
```

If it works, it could be optimized to have all partial sums precomputed.

UPDATE

Sampling above relies on the fact, that Dirichlet could be sampled via beta variate, and that is better (but slower) choice if case of small parameters. In turn, beta variate could be sampled as pair of gamma variates:

```
beta(a, b) = gamma(1, a) / (gamma(1, a) + gamma(1, b))
```

So small parameters are moved from being first in gamma (if you sample Dirichlet directly via gamma variates) to being second. And 1 (one) being first in gamma-variates means they are just exponential distribution, sampled as -log(U(0,1)). Please check if my math is ok, but that way sampling might work

Comment: First, I am impressed, that you completely avoid numpy in this solution! Second, I think there might be a typo in your sample method. I think it should be `return x / (x + y*beta/alpha)`. I will try to use this in my application after I did some speed tests and will also look into your proposed efficiency enhancement. Thanks a lot already

Comment: @MillaWell wrt a typo in sampling, there might be one, please see update.